Activating IK straightens the armature unwillingly
For some reason when I try to add IK to the legs of my model, the legs are automatically straightened out.
This does not happen with the model's hands.
Why is it happening and how do I fix it?
File:

IK activated without a pole:

IK activated with a pole:

IK diactivated:


The tail of IK bone will automatically jump to its target's head as soon as you'll switch to Pose mode, so it's better to have it already sticking to the target's head in Edit mode (use ShiftS to do so):

Also maybe move a bit the knee and target so that the leg is flat in front view:

Ideally I suppose it would be even better if you do a SX0 of the whole leg:

